# How to perform jQuery slideToggle() equivalent in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

The basic idea is to produce jQuery's slideToggle() animation in reactjs.

Hiding an element and showing it based on its state is fairly straightforward, but actually animating the height, so it looks like it's sliding up and down, seems to be more complex than I thought in reactjs. I've googled around for this type of animation and cannot find anything.

The closest I've found is people saying use the "max-height" css property and animate with that, however, that requires you to set a max-height on all divs you want to animate. And with responsive content this is just not the right way to go. On one screen the max height needed might be 200, but on mobile maybe 500!

Here is where I am so far, I can easily collapse/expand a component with the state like I said, but how do I expand this to actually animate? And handle mid animation clicks, so it goes back when needed?

The height-0 css class is just this:

```
.height-0 {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}



import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class CollapsableComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: false
    };
  }

  toggleCollapse(){
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      collapsed: this.state.collapsed ? false : true;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h2>Some Title....
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" onClick={this.toggleCollapse}>
              <span class={`fa fa-${collapsed ? 'expand' : 'compress'}`} aria-hidden="true"/>
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div class={`animation-holder${collapsed ? ' height-0' : ''}`} ref={(div) => { this.holderDiv = div;}}>
            <p>content here......</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is the following: [Sandbox](https://z8uke.csb.app/)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const style = {
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: isOpen ? 50 : 0,
    transition: "2s"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={style}>
        <p> Let me slide in and out!</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}>Slide Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

If the want the actual height of the component you could retrieve it with the use of the `useRef` hook like this: `ref.current.clientHeight`.